# How come in these questions we treat the sum of exponential distribution as an exponential dist.?

Tags: probability

[image]

In problems like these, all the solutions I've seen add the lambda value of one device n times (in this case n = 6) for a system. Then they find the probability like they would for exponential distribution. But I thought the sum of exponential distributions was a gamma distribution. How come we are  able to solve the probability for the system like we would for one device using exponential distribution formulas?

Here lambda = .1 for one device, and thus for the system, lambda = .1 * 6 = .6

Comment: You’ve misunderstood the question.  It is saying that the system uses six of the devices and all six must continue to function for the system to function.  The system fails As soon as any of the six devices fail.  Thus you need the minimum of the six times to failure rather than the sum.

Answer (score 2):

The system fails as soon as one component fails. Thus the lifetime of the system is the *minimum* of the six components' lifetimes (not the *sum* of the lifetimes). Your textbook probably proves that the minimum of $n$ independent $\text{Exponential}(\lambda)$ random variables is itself a $\text{Exponential}(n\lambda)$ random variable.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the minimum of exponential random variables (RV) is also an exponential random variable. In particular, if the PDF of RV $X_i$ is 
$$f_{X_i}(x) = \lambda_i \exp{(-\lambda_i x)},$$
$Y = \min\{X_1, X_2,\cdots, X_n\}$, and $X_i$ are independent RVs then
\begin{align}
\Pr\{Y > y\} & = \Pr\{X_1 >y \}\cdot \Pr\{X_2 >y \}\cdots \Pr\{X_n >y \}\\
& = \exp(-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\cdots \lambda_n)y)\\
\therefore f_Y(y) & = \lambda \exp(-\lambda y),
\end{align}
where $\lambda = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots +\lambda_n$.

In your question, you need to consider the minimum of the six random variables as the system fails if *at least* one of them fails.